# Abbreviation of editors in amsrefs package

Tags: bibtex, amsrefs

I face a problem with `amsrefs`, which seems like a bug. I know that if we want to only show the first author/editor of a book, we can write the corresponding fields as `Editor={First, Author and others}`, there the key is `and others` keywords, which will produce and `et al.` for the reference.

This works for most cases, but fails in the following example of `amsrefs` and `author-year` cite style.

The MME

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[alphabetic]{amsrefs} %author-year

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book {Deligne1999Quantum,
  TITLE = {Quantum fields and strings: a course for mathematicians.
           {V}ol. 1, 2},
  EDITOR = {Deligne, Pierre and others},
  PUBLISHER = {American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI; Institute for
               Advanced Study (IAS), Princeton, NJ},
  YEAR = {1999},
  PAGES = {Vol. 1: xxii+723 pp.; Vol. 2: pp. i--xxiv and 727--1501},
  ISBN = {0-8218-1198-3},
  MRCLASS = {81-06 (81T30 81Txx)},
  MRNUMBER = {1701618},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Just for test, we know that \ocite{Deligne1999Quantum}...
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

If we change the style from `alphabetic` to `author-year` then the above example will fails, which is caused by the `and others` in EDITOR fields.

Comment: If it turns out that this is indeed a bug (I can't really investigate at the moment, but to me it certainly looks suspicious), then please also report this to the package maintainers directly via the appropriate channels listed in the documentation. Stackexchange is not a bug tracker and even though many paclage authors are active here, there is always a chance a question posted here falls through the cracks.

Comment: I did a bit of digging and I still can't explain exactly why this error appears, but I am becoming more and more convinced that this is indeed a bug.

Comment: I *think* I have tracked this down to the definition of `\calc@alpha@suffix` where macros (such as `\etaltext`, which is what `others` ends up being) cause a few problems when they are unexpandable (`\etaltext` is made unexpandable with `\auto@protect` a few steps earlier).